# Computing time difference to fraction in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Consider an employee working 8 hours a day (9AM-6PM), and came in 9:25AM, had a break at 12:00 - 1:00PM and logged out at 6PM. I use a formula to get hours worked (7.58) -

```
 =IF((((C4-B4)+(E4-D4))*24)>8,8,((C4-B4)+(E4-D4))*24)
```

My question is how do I show the 25min late as "time" in another column?

Comment: what does your input data look like, post some samples.

Answer (score 0):

If your 7.58 is in cell **A1**, you could try the following formula:

`=(8-A1)*60`

or

`=FLOOR((8-A1),1)&" Hours "&MOD((8-A1)*60,60)&" Minutes"`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your formula `=IF((((C4-B4)+(E4-D4))*24)>8,8,((C4-B4)+(E4-D4))*24)` is giving hours worked in decimal form. If you multiply that by 60 (minutes) you get worked minutes. If you subtract those minutes from 480 minutes (8 hours) you get the amount of minutes the employee was late.

You can use a formula like this -

```
 =IF((((C4-B4)+(E4-D4))*24)>=8,"8h","8h "&ROUNDUP(480-(((C4-B4)+(E4-D4))*24*60),0)&"m")
```